# viewing top lines of big error outputs

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, head

During compilation process many errors are thrown on the screen. To start resolving them I need to scroll up 3, 4 pages. I tried doing head on them but they still came on the terminal.

```
g++ -std=c++0x testCoverDownloader.cpp -I /usr/include/QtCore/ -I /usr/include/QtGui 2>&1 | head
```

how to I just see the top errors first and then scroll down the page? The code above cuts the output to show the top 10 lines. What I want is all errors but from the start so that I dont need to scroll upwards

Comment: If you use vim you could try `<your compile statement> 2>&1 | vim -` That should pipe STDERR and STDOUT to vim for viewing.

Comment: or `<your compile statement> 2>&1 | more` . (with help from Michael's  comment)

Comment: The important part of the comment from @Michael is the redirection part: Error from the compiler is put on `stderr`. To pipe it to `head`, a viewer like `more` or `less` or even an editor like `vim`, you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. This is what is done with the `&2>1` (or more correctly `2>&1`). See the manual page of your shell for more information about redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use vim you could try `<your compile statement> 2>&1 | vim -` That should pipe `STDERR` and `STDOUT` to vim for viewing.

EDIT:
Added in `@joachim pilberg`'s comment to provide a more accurate answer:

> The important part is the redirection part: Error from the compiler is
>   put on stderr. To pipe it to head, a viewer like more or less or even
>   an editor like vim, you need to redirect stderr to stdout. This is
>   what is done with the &2>1 (or more correctly 2>&1). See the manual
>   page of your shell for more information about redirection.

Comment: [vickey@tb tests]$ g++ testCoverDownloader.cpp ../CoverDownloader.cpp -I /usr/include/QtGui/ -I /usr/include/QtCore/ -lQtGui -lQtCore -std=c++0x 2>&1 | vim
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.

Comment: `g++ testCoverDownloader.cpp ../CoverDownloader.cpp -I /usr/include/QtGui/ -I /usr/include/QtCore/ -lQtGui -lQtCore -std=c++0x 2>&1 | vim -` I think you might have been missing the final `-`

Comment: yeah :P .. thats the solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

As well as using 2>&1 to get the STDERR results to STDOUT, you might want to try tee in order to get the results into a file for later viewing.

Answer (score 1):

you can also add -Wfatal-errors compiler option to stop compilation after first error